# FaceBook SDK3.5 closeAndClearTokenInformation calls completion handler of openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions

Tags: ios6, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-login

I have the following code that I use during facebook login.

```
- (BOOL)openFBSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI
            withCompletionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler
{

    NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                        @"user_photos",
                        @"email",
                        nil];
    return [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
       if (error != nil) {
        ...
       } else {
            switch (state) {
               case FBSessionStateOpen:
               {
                   ...
               }
               case FBSessionStateClosed:
               {
                   ...
               }
               case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
               {
                   ...
               }
               default:
                   break;
           }
       }
   }];
}
```

The above works fine for login.  But, when I log out using the following code

```
[FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
```

this again calls the completionHandler of openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions allowLoginUI:.  That does not make sense to me.  I do not think it is the right behavior.  Has anyone seen this problem?  How do we log-out?  I am using SDK 3.5 on iOS6.

Comment: Then post your entire code dealing with facebook FBSession.

Comment: SDK 3.10 still has this behavior. Interestingly the official SessionLoginSample depends on it to refresh the UI after pressing the "Log out" button.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this thread](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/127289947439471) on the Facebook Developer bug tracker, this behavior is "by design".

In fact, I did suggest a better name for this method would be: `openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:allowLoginUI:stateChangeHandler:`

as that more accurately describes what's happening (the "completionHandler" is in fact called on state change).

You can handle this in several ways: [Ben Cohen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2799/benedict-cohen) suggest you can either set the `completionHandler` to `nil` within the completion block (to ensure run-once), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17197945/346098) suggests creating an `FBSessionStateHandler` run-once handler, or you can switch on the state change.

Ideally, as we rely on the Facebook SDK for specific purposes (log in, log out, make requests, etc.), these would be provided via delegates, but since the SDK developers apparently got a bit carried away with "ooh blocks!!", you're left having to define your state change handler at the point where you first open your session.

Comment: Other than the "hack" proposed by Adam Wallner as possible answer in this same thread, another solution to the problem is to check inside the completion block the effective state of FB session:
if(state==FBSessionStateOpen || state==FBSessionStateOpenTokenExtended) {
 // just logged in...
} else if(error) {
 // error while logging in...
} else {
 // closed
}

Answer (score 0):

This is a very bad behavior I think.

FBSession has a hidden property:

```
@property (readwrite, copy) FBSessionStateHandler loginHandler;
```

So you can set it to nil by this code in the block like this:

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:FACEBOOK_PERMISSIONS
                                           allowLoginUI:NO
                                      completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Warc-performSelector-leaks"
                                          [[FBSession activeSession] performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"setLoginHandler:") withObject:nil];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
                                          // Your stuff...
                                      }];
```